# Mysql multiple maching patterns in substring_index

Tags: mysql

Can I use something like `case` to give multiple matching patterns in `substring_index`?

More specifically in my case, can I matching a set of chars according to their ascii?

Add some examples:

```
中文Q100
中文T800
中文中文K999
```

The strings start with some Chinese characters, then following by some numbers or latin letters, what I want is to split the string into two parts: one contains the Chinese characters(from leftmost to the first western letter), the other is from the first western letter to the rightmost.

Like these:

```
中文, Q100
中文, T800
中文中文, K999
```

Comment: It would be better to give an example. But `CASE` will typically use the first condition that evaluates to true, so it will get complicated.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Make some samples in source set and desired result row set. Try to explain with at least "pseudo"-SQL. For now it's unclear

Comment: @AlmaDo examples added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways to resolve a matter. I'll give you 3 of them, starting from most right.

## Architecture solution

**Using application**

Your question is about - replacing by regular expression. And that has a weak support in MySQL (to say precisely, there's no support for replacing by regex). Thus, you may do: select whole record, then split it in applicaition, using `a-zA-Z0-9` mask, for example.

**Or may be change table structure?**

Well, alternative is: may be you should just separate this data to 2 columns? If your intention is to work with separate parts of data, then may be it's a sign to change your DB architecture?

## Using MySQL

Second way is to use MySQL. To do it - yes, you'll use `REPLACE()` as it is. For instance, to get rid of all alphanumeric symbols, you'll do:

```
SELECT [...REPLACE(REPLACE(str, 'z', ''), 'y', '')...]
```

that is a pseudo-SQL, since posting whole 26+26+10 instances of `REPLACE` would be mad (however, using this is also mad). But that will resolve your issue, of course.

## Using external REGEXP solution

This is third way and it has two subcases. You may either use UDF or stored routines.

**Using UDF**

There are third-party libraries which provide regular expression replacement functionality. Then all you need to do is to include those libraries into your server build. Example: [**lib_mysqludf_preg**](https://github.com/mysqludf/lib_mysqludf_preg) This, however, will require additional actions to use those libraries.

**Using stored routines**

Well, you can use stored routines to create your own replacement function. Actually, I have already written such library, it's called [`mysql-regexp`](https://github.com/almadomundo/mysql-regexp) and it provides `REGEXP_REPLACE()` function, which allows you to do replacements in strings by regular expressions. It's not well-tested, so if you'll decide to use it - do that on your own risk. Sample would be:

```
mysql> SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('foo bar34 b103az 98feo', '[^a-z]', '');
+--------------------------------------------------------+
| REGEXP_REPLACE('foo bar34 b103az 98feo', '[^a-z]', '') |
+--------------------------------------------------------+
| foobarbazfeo                                           |
+--------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Since it's completely written with stored code, you won't need to re-build your server or whatever.

Comment: Thank you for giving such detailed solutions.

Comment: Actually, my goal is trying to change the architecture of the DB, I need to separate the column into two, to fulfill the 1NF of database.
According to your post, I think using application and regex may be the easiest solution, and I'll try in this way.
Much appreciated.